# Check for docker installation programmatically (sh-script)

Tags: shell-script

Is it possible to check via shell script if docker is installed.

I would check this manually by

```
sudo docker run --name hello-world-container hello-world
sudo docker rm hello-world-container
```

But I would like to check this programmatically, so if this test fails, the install routine could be started.

**Update**

```
#!/bin/bash

which docker

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    docker --version | grep "Docker version"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "docker existing"
    else
        echo "install docker"
    fi
else
    echo "install docker" >&2
fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try executing:

```
which docker
```

and testing the exit code of that command. If it's 0 (successful), you could then execute:

```
docker --version
```

and grep for a known name and version pattern.

Comment: Isn't it enough to check `which docker`? why do I have to check for `docker --version` after this? And how can I test the exit code?

Comment: You could satisfy yourself with the exit code from the `which` command, but inspecting the output from the `docker --version` command is extra assurance that it is the `docker` executable that you expect instead of some other executable or script that shares the name.

As for testing the exit code, I see that your edited question contains a solution.

Comment: I think the `docker --version` would be better as you explained, but I don't know how to check for that because it is a string from which I want to get the version number (which should not be undefined).

Comment: You would execute `docker --version | grep "Docker version"`. If the exit code is `0`, there is a successful match and the executable is likely the Docker executable.

Comment: Oh, ok. Understand that. Is it possible to combine both into one? I have updated my post. As you can see my attempt looks very bad... :-(

Comment: You could execute this: `which docker && docker --version | grep "Docker version"` and test for the exit code of the combined command.

If there is no `docker` executable available, the `which docker` command will exit with a failure and the second half of the command won't run. If, however, it is found, the second half executes, which will return a successful exit code if `grep` finds a match.